# Ignore Auditing fields from Spring Boot API Response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am searching for a better approach, that how to either exclude the auditing fields(like createdBy,createdDate) while fetching the @Entity in Data repository class or ignore them in API response. I know we can do it by using @Ignore or @IgnoreProperties on each property or entity class, but not interested to add it in every class , reason i have too many entities.

Is there any other approach to achieve with simple and with common implementation?

Answer (score 0):

If all auditing fields have the same name, Use an abstract class to manage those fields, then other entirety extend from it;

here is my approach:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener::class)
abstract class ModifiedJpaEntity:Serializable {
    companion object {
        private const val serialVersionUID = -5554308939380869754L
    }
    @Column
    @CreationTimestamp
    @JsonIgnore
    var createAt:Date?=null
    @Column
    @CreatedBy
    @JsonIgnore
    var createBy:String?=null
    @Column
    @UpdateTimestamp
    @JsonIgnore
    var updateAt:Date?=null
    @Column
    @LastModifiedBy
    @JsonIgnore
    var updateBy:String?=null

    val createTimeStr: String
        get() = if(createAt!=null) SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").format(createAt) else ""
    val updateTimeStr: String
        get() = if(updateAt!=null) SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").format(updateAt) else ""
}
```

Comment: Agree. I like to learn if there is another way to handle it, or is it better approach.